# Garbage Collection in the JVM

Tags: java, list, garbage

I was wondering when you remove a node in a linked list, does the garbage collection immediately remove it or does it get accumulated in a buffer which then removes it later on after it gets capped? This is in relation to running in the JVM. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Google around for how garbage collection works in Java. You'll find answers aplenty.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science), then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection .